# NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID: certificate is getting invalid when I am using multiple level subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have created a domain certificate on AWS. For example *.dev.example.com

Now I am trying to create an ingress controller with host **a.foo.dev.example.com** and **b.bar.dev.example.com**. But I am getting certificate invalid issue(NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID). when I am hitting any of the 2 links, app is opening but not secure. how can I fix this issue??

P.S I can create and application works with foo.dev.example.com and bar.dev.example.com

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a wildcard certificate to match more than one level deep.  This is a universal restriction on wildcard certificates, not a limitation in Amazon Certificate Manager.

You would need certificate supporting both `*.foo.dev.example.com` and `*.bar.dev.example.com` or one certificate for each, if you want to use this naming convention.

You also can't obtain a certificate for `*.*.dev.example.com`, which looks like it might work, but it won't.